# Applescript content of incoming iMessage

Tags: applescript, imessage

I need to extract/read the content of an incoming Message received via iMessage. I am having a hard time finding out the right command to extract the info. Could someone point me in the right direction ?
I know I don't have much so far, I am a newbie :(

```
using terms from application "Messages"
on message received theMessage
return theMessage

end message received
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look examples provided in ElCapitain your user Library / Application Scripts / com.apple.iChat, there is "Mix message Case.applescript file which contains syntax for each case of message (received, send, invitation,...)

According to that file, you must add attribute to the "on message received" like :

```
on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat
```

Comment: Thanks. I spent all day on it, but can't figure it out.